# freeing memory in a while loop keeps getting stuck an infinite loop

Tags: c

I just wanted this while loop to go through each slot of `party -> fragments` and free each spot if it isn't NULL, but it seems to be getting stuck in an infinite loop instead when I go to run it. If I insert an else and put a break in it, it'll run, but I still have memory leaks.

```
  while(i < party -> num_active_fragments)
  {
    if(party -> fragments[i] != NULL)
    {
      free(party -> fragments[i]);
      i++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Using `free` on a pointer which is `NULL` is perfectly okay. So remove the check. Most likely `i` doesn't get incremented enough to reach the condition. Can't know for sure with the given code.

Comment: Don't put spaces around `" -> "` -- and what is the value of `i` to begin with? Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `i++` should be out of the if statement. The infite loop is caused because an element is NULL and `i` is never incremented

Comment: Use `for (int i = 0; i < party->num_active_fragments; i++) free(party->fragments[i]);` — it is harder for a simple loop like that to go wrong.

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff this solved it thank you so much, im still getting memory leaks though which im trying to figure out. Edit; puting `<=` fixed the memory leak, thank you again

Comment: You better assign `NULL` to the fragments you just free'd. @EduardoPascualAseff Please make this an answer for DingleBox to mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get an infinite loop is `i` is only incremented if `party->fragments[i]` is not `NULL`.

It is less error prone to use `for` for this type of loop and not modify the loop index inside the body of the loop:

```c
for (i = 0; i < party->num_active_fragments; i++) {
    if (party->fragments[i] != NULL) {
        free(party->fragments[i]);
    }
}
```

Furthermore, you can pass null pointers to `free` that will ignore them and you should set the freed pointers to `NULL` to avoid later reference:

```c
for (i = 0; i < party->num_active_fragments; i++) {
    free(party->fragments[i]);
    party->fragments[i] = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that `i++` should be out of the if statement. 
The infite loop is caused because an element is NULL and in that iteration `i` is not incremented, and same happens repeatedly.

As people commented, there is no need for checking if the value is NULL.

And as @thebusybee commented, you should set the freed pointers as NULL.

Your code may look like this:

```
while(i < party->num_active_fragments)
{
    free(party->fragments[i]);
    party->fragments[i] = NULL;    
    i++;
}
```

Comment: You might also hint that `i` should be initialized at the beginning of the loop and that a `for` loop is less error prone for this type of iteration.

Comment: A for loop would be better. Makes the code more readable imho